# R reshape dataframe for only one column

Tags: r, reshape

I've got a data frame which I'm trying to reshape the first column as new headers. I've have tried to Google this and use Stack Overflow but couldn't find anything that matched my questions

Here's a simplistic example of what I'm trying do. I've got a data frame like the below

```
    v1 v2 v3 v4
1    A  B  1  0
2    C  D  3  0
```

This can be obtained:

```
v1 <- matrix(c("A", "C"), nrow=2, ncol=1) 
v2 <- matrix(c("B", "D"), nrow=2, ncol=1) 
v3 <- c(1,3)
v4 <- c(0,0)

data <-  cbind(v1,v2,v3,v4)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
```

I am trying to convert the data to the below

```
| V2 | A.V3 | A.V4 | C.V3 | C.V4 |
| B  |   1  |   2  |   0  |   0  |
| D  |   0  |   0  |   3  |   4  |
```

I tried messing round with the reshape package but couldn't get it to work the way I wanted.

Thanks,
Shan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not put an effort to show what you have tried, I will assume you have a data called "data". I will also assume you made typos in Table 2 where the values of "2" and "4" magically appear, although they do not in Table 1. Nevertheless, the following should provide the desired result.

reshape(data, idvar = "v2", timevar = "v1", v.names = c("v3", "v4"), direction = "wide")

Comment: Apologies about that Rebecca, I have tried a few things such as melt and dcast from the reshape2 package but kept getting errors or losing data. I didn't post the code as I thought it was all wrong! I tried reading the documentation on the function reshape as I couldn't get it to work completely with my dataset. I have more than one categorical column in my dataset that I don't want to move which I should have used in my example. If improved my example, how would I get it to work I had a V5 column that was categorical?

Comment: The same code should apply. All columns you do not want to move should be left out from v.names.

Comment: Thanks Rebecca, apologies again for the poor post!